# Contar Texbox Llenos en C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Compañeros, Soy totalmente novato en C# y no estoy muy familiarizado con los eventos.

Estoy en un dilema espero me puedan ayudar, tengo este pequeño formulario con una serie de textBox y lo que estoy intentando hacer es contar los textbox llenos para asi imprimir el número de "bultos Total", es decir cada campo lleno es un bulto.

Tengo este código con el evento Keyup de cada textBox, "fecha de Llegada" que básicamente verifica si el tamaño del campo "cantidad de tubos" es mayor a 0, entonces cuento 1 y así sucesivamente hasta 6. Hace la cuenta la correctamente, el detalle es:

¿Como hacer para decrementar la cantidad de bultos Total cuando un textbox se vacia?
es decir que si lleno todos los campos el total de bultos va a ser 6 pero si luego borro 1 campos decremente a 5 y asi sucesivamente.

Espero haberme dado a entender y desde YA gracias por sus comentarios

```
private void txtbFechaLl1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (txtbCantTubo1.Text.Length > 0 )
        {
            txtbBultosTotal.Text = "1";
        }
        
    }

    private void txtbFechaLl2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbCantTubo1.Text.Length > 0 && txtbCantTubo2.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            txtbBultosTotal.Text = "2";
        }
    }
    private void txtbFechaLl3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbCantTubo1.Text.Length > 0 && txtbCantTubo2.Text.Length > 0 && txtbCantTubo3.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            txtbBultosTotal.Text = "3";
        }
    }
```

.
.
.

[image: conteo de textbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una sugerencia para resolverlo es la siguiente:

- Utilizar el evento `Leave` que ocurre cuando el textbox es abandonado o pierde el foco.
- Crear un método `ContadorDeBultos` que verifique los textbox `txtbCantTubo..`, haga la cuenta y asigne el resultado en `txtbBultosTotal`.
- Invocar el método `ContadorDeBultos` en el evento `Leave`

Por ejemplo:

```
    //Este es el método contador de bultos
    private void ContadorDeBultos()
    {
        int cantidad = 0;

        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo1.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;

        // Ten en cuenta que la instrucción anterior es equivalente a
        // if (txtbCantTubo1.Text.Length > 0)
        // {
        //     cantidad++;
        // }
        // else
        // {
        //     cantidad--;
        // }

        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo2.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo3.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo4.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo5.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        cantidad += (txtbCantTubo6.Text.Length > 0) ? 1 : -1;

        //esta comprobación es por si se pasean por todos los textbox sin escribir nada
        if(cantidad < 0)
        {
            cantidad = 0;
        }

        txtbBultosTotal.Text = cantidad.ToString();
    }
```

Ya con el método que hace la cuenta, lo que falta es invocarlo en los eventos

```
    private void txtbCantTubo1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContadorDeBultos();
    }
```

Te comento que, en este caso, puedes asignar el mismo manejador de evento en todos los `txtbCantTubo...`.

Como medida de control adicional, puedes invocar el método `ContadorDeBultos()` en cualquier otra parte que lo consideres necesario. Por ejemplo, en un método de validación general previo a guardar la información.

Cabe destacar que mi propuesta es una posible solución, pero no es la única.

**Actualización (suscripciones a eventos)**

Sospecho que los errores que mencionas en tu comentario, están relacionados con la suscripción a los eventos. Ese funcionamiento que describes me hace pensar que falta la suscripción en los primeros 3.

Además de crear el método `txtbCantTubo1_Leave`, también es necesario establecer una especie de mapeo entre el método y el evento correspondiente.

Para hacer eso, selecciona los `txtbCantTubo...` (uno a la vez) y revisa en la ventana de propiedades, en la sección de eventos, que el evento Leave esté asociado al método correspondiente, similar a como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes crear un solo método `txtbCantTubo_Leave` y asociarlo en los 6 `txtbCantTubo`. Pero la asociación debe estar en los 6.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta compañero, ya mismo estoy implementandola solo que tengo ciertos errores en teoria deberia funcionar tal como la escribiste pero a la hora de dejar el primer texbox deja el contador en 0 y no es hasta que deja el 4 texbox que empieza a contar en 2 lo raro tambien es que en el 6to textbox ya da el conteo en 6 y al decrementar hace exactamente lo mismo con los texbox 4 decrementa.

Comment: @JrojasE, revisa que en cada uno de los `txtbCantTubo...` tengas una suscipción al evento `Leave`. En mi ejemplo hice referencia a uno solo pero debes tenerlo en los 6.

Comment: En efecto tengo  ` private void txtbCantTubo1...hasta..6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContadorDeBultos();
        }`    no se si deberia fijarme en alguna otra propiedad del Textbox

Comment: @JrojasE, hice una actualización a mi respuesta con el procedimiento para la suscripción a los eventos.

Comment: Gracias Amigo por tu ayuda